# MS SQL calculate sub sub groups % of sub grouop total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a time series table with the following fields:

- Timestamp: DateTime
- MachineNr: String [1,2,3...]
- Status: String [Production, Alarm, Stopped, Off, Unknown]
- Duration: Int

I wish to get the breakdown of % time spent in diffrent states for each machine to a table that looks like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      MachineNr      |     %_Alarm      |   %_Production   | %_Unknown etc...
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         10       |         56       |       ....
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         7        |         59       |       ....
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

In python(Pandas) I would just do:
(df=pandasDataframe)

```
df_utilisation=df.groupby(['MachineNr','Status']).sum()['Duration']
df_utilisation_procentage=df_utilisation/df_utilisation.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

But how do i do the same in sql? 
The example code almost work but divides by the total duration sum and not the right tabel layout.

```
SELECT MachineNr
       ,Status
       ,SUM(Duration)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) 
FROM my_table group by MachineNr,Status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT MachineNr, Status
       SUM(Duration)/SUM(SUM(Duration)) OVER (PARTITION BY MachineNR) as ratio
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY MachineNr, Status;
```

If you want this in one row, use conditional aggregation:

```
select machinenr,
       sum(case when status = 'production' then duration else 0 end) / sum(duration) as production,
       sum(case when status = 'alarm' then duration else 0 end) / sum(duration) as alarm,
       . . . 
from my_table
group by machinenr;
```